# Is there any function in discord.py 2.0 where the bot responds in the same way if the same message was called?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot, and one of the commands is like a "gaycount" random number generation command, I've made it fine but I want functionality where if the same message was said twice it would show the same results as the first one.

e.g: a person pings @user with !gay, it shows that they're 68% gay. if they ping @user again with the command !gay again, it'll show the same result - 68%, instead of showing its random number generated as 49%.

I've tried making a specific ping/mention command but each time someone pings a person I'm pretty sure the bot picks up a ping as "<@userid>" so I can't really do that, I'll need to make some intricate JSON file that me personally cannot be bothered to do.

Any help on this?

Comment: Use a database to store the result

Comment: You can use MySQL or SQL databases to store the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a small json database.

Code logic:

```
@bot.command()
async def gay(ctx, arg):
   with open("database path", "a+") as data:
       Database = json.loads(data)
   #arg = ping
   if arg in Database["pings"]        # ˘˘ getting info from db ˘˘
       ctx.send(f"Your custom message {Database["pings"][str(arg)]}%")
   else:
       #generate random % number
       #send that number and save it to database
```

Database should look like this:

```
{
 "pings":{

   "userping1" : 10,
   "userping2" : 37,
     ..........
   }
}
```

Comment: is the 10 and 37 random numbers or do I need to make it store the user IDs?

Comment: Yeah, 10 and 37 are random generated numbers from your % generator. `userping` is `arg`. Database should look like this `"<@1516363161337>" : 7`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, will try making the command work